# MPI symbol lookup error: opal_uses_threads

Tags: runtime-error, mpi, undefined-symbol

SO: Ubuntu 17.04. Until yesterday everything was fine with MPI, then something went wrong. The error is the one on the the title and it comes out running with `mpirun -n[n] ./myprogram`.
Before *Opal* the error was with *Libmpi.so.12* and I couldn't resolve it despite I tried indicating the LD_LIBRARY_PATH on my `.bashrc`, as suggested in similar questions here. Then reinstalling OpenMPI the error has changed in this new one, and I don't know how to fix it. Actually the result of `apt-file search libmpi.so` is:

```
lam4-dev: /usr/lib/lam/lib/libmpi.so
libopenmpi-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so
libopenmpi2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20
libopenmpi2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20.0.2
libopenmpi2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.20.0.2
```

And `ldd` returns:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc415e5000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe717956000)
libmpi.so.12 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe717738000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe717371000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055ccd14f4000)
```

So the problem still seems to be *libmpi.so.12* ? Before reinstalling OpenMPI, libmpi.so.12 was there, MPI couldn't find it, but was there.

[edit]

`which mpirun` returns:

```
/usr/bin/mpirun
```

And `apt-file search mpicc` returns:

```
lam4-dev: /usr/bin/mpicc.lam
lam4-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.lam.1.gz
libmpich-dev: /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
libmpich-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.mpich.1.gz
libopenmpi-dev: /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi
libopenmpi-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.openmpi.1.gz
libsimgrid-dev: /usr/bin/smpicc
libsimgrid-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/smpicc.1.gz
mpich-doc: /usr/share/doc/mpich-doc/www1/mpicc.html
openmpi-common: /usr/share/openmpi/mpicc-wrapper-data.txt
openmpi-common: /usr/share/openmpi/mpicc.openmpi-wrapper-data.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems your application was built with an other MPI version (an older Open MPI or an other MPI library such as lam or mpich)

The easiest path is to rebuild your application with the freshly installed Open MPI

**[EDIT]**

this was diagnosed in the chat, and the root cause was system and user built Open MPI were inadvertently mixed.

once the environment was fixed so only the system Open MPI is used, the issue was resolved.

Comment: I'm simply compiling it with `mpicc ...`. How can I compile with the freshly installed Open MPI?

Comment: Make sure `mpicc` is the one provided by Open MPI, and then rebuild your app from scratch, it will likely be enough.

Comment: Note you should not need anything in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Ok, what I'm asking is how can I be sure `mpicc` is the one provided by Open MPI?

Comment: `which mpirun` and `apt-file search mpicc` should do the trick.

Comment: What does `alternatives --display mpicc` reports ?

Comment: You can also try `apt-file search libmpi.so.12`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153365/discussion-between-imworsethanyou-and-gilles-gouaillardet).